# PHP (5.5), WebMatrix, SMTP and windows

Tags: php, email

I am looking for some good information on setting up SMTP on windows 7 to be used with WebMatrix and PHP5.5

I have tried a few standard YouTube tutorials but they either lack the integration between SMTP and PHP or they outright ignore SMTP setup and configuration, all the others use Linux or MacOSx.

I don't really mind which solution to use as long as it can be easily ported to Unix, additionally to test the SMTP settings I found a "quick and dirty" script to use which I will put below.

I am quite new to SMTP and PHP so the only thing I know for certain is I should change the email in the code but cant see where I should tell it to use localhost as a server.
Thanks for any help.

Test Script:

```
<?php
/*
DONT FORGET TO DELETE THIS SCRIPT WHEN FINISHED!
*/
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

$from = 'webmaster@example.com';

/*
ini_set( 'SMTP', 'smtp.example.com' );
ini_set( 'SMTP_PORT', 25 );
ini_set( 'sendmail_from', $from );
*/

$server = array( 
    'HTTP_HOST', 'SERVER_NAME', 'SERVER_ADDR', 'SERVER_PORT',
    'SERVER_ADMIN', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 
    'REMOTE_ADDR', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'REQUEST_URI', 
    'SCRIPT_NAME', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME',
);

$to      = ( isset( $_GET['email'] ) ? $_GET['email'] : FALSE );
$subject = 'Mail Test Successful for ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$message = '';

if ( ! $to )
{
    echo '<strong>Set $_GET[\'email\'].</strong>';
    exit;
};

foreach ( $server as $s )
{
    $message .= sprintf( '%s: %s', $s, $_SERVER[$s] ) . PHP_EOL;
};

$headers = 'From: ' . $from . PHP_EOL 
     . 'Reply-To: ' . $from . PHP_EOL 
     . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

if ( isset( $_GET['send'] ) && $_GET['send'] === 'true' )
{                   
    $success = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
else
{
    echo '<strong>Set &quot;<a href="./?email=' . $to . '&send=true">'
     . './?email=' . $to . '&send=true</a>&quot; to send a test e-mail.</strong>';
};

if ( isset( $success ) )
{   
    echo 'E-mail sent to: ' . $to;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Successful mail?: <strong ' . ( $success ? 'style="color:green;">YES' : 'style="color:red;">NO' ) . '</strong>';
}
else
{
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'E-mail set as: '.$to;
};

echo '<hr />';  
echo '<style>   * { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  } th { text-align: left; } td { padding: 3px 5px; } </style>';
echo '<table>'; 

foreach ( $server as $s )
{
    echo '<tr><th>$_SERVER[\'' . $s . '\']</th><td>' . $_SERVER[$s] . '</td></tr>';
};

echo '</table>';

if ( isset( $success ) )
{
    echo '<!--'; 
    var_dump( $success );       
    echo '-->';
};
?>
```

Comment: One of the worst topics ever, only consisting of things that belong in the tags. I'm confident you can do better!

Comment: sorry its been a very long day. I'll try better.

Comment: 1. Don't use the `mail()` function. Use a mail library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that opens a socket so you can control and debug what happens.
2. I don't recommend running your own SMTP server (there's a ton of pitfalls there). I would highly suggest getting a SMTP service to relay the emails for you (i.e. Amazon SES)

Comment: This is purely for testing so having some complex library would be a little overkill, same with using SMTP services. The Unix system i have to port it to uses its own SMTP service so having that working means i can test it better, rather than outsourcing it all.